# Android : Get the maximum value of light sensor

Tags: android, algorithm, android-sensors

For my app I need to get the maximum value of light sensor. I thought it was the same for all devices which have light sensor (ie SensorManager.LIGHT_SUNLIGHT_MAX) but according to sample tests made on devices I was wrong.

The problem is that with SensorListener you can only know when the value has changed.

So my question is: How to get maximum value of light sensor (assuming that the user can put a powerfull light in front of the sensor that, ie light value > maximum sensor value) ?

A solution could be looking at value growth but I don't know how to manage it.

Answer (score 4):

Use following method :

```
getMaximumRange()
```

Implementation :

```
SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
Sensor lightSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT);
maxvalue = lightSensor.getMaximumRange();
```

Source :

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#getMaximumRange()

Comment: getMaximumRange() returns value above 10000, while light sensor event gives value 0 when it's dark and value 5 when it's pretty much sunny outside. The biggest value I could get from event was ~50 in well lit room. Tested on galaxy SIII.

Comment: I got more than 2000! Try to put the flash of another smartphone on your light sensor!

Comment: getMaximumRange() returns 3000 for me but the sensor returns values from 10 to 16000! It seems like you can't rely on the maximum range value!